# How to initialize a static const set<string> in implementation file?

Tags: c++, static, set, constants

My initialisation of a `static const set<string>` appears to be incorrect, I'd appreciate your guidelines on this:

`obj.h`:

```
class obj
{
  ...

private:
  static const set<string> keywords;
  ...

}
```

`obj.cpp`:

```
const string kw[] = {"GTR","LTR","LEQ","GEQ","NEQ","SQRT","sqrt"};
const set<string> obj::keywords = (kw,kw + sizeof(kw)/sizeof(kw[0]));
```

But this yields the error:
`error: conversion from ‘const string* {aka const std::basic_string<char>*}’ to non-scalar type ‘const std::set<std::basic_string<char> >’ requested`

Can somebody tell me the correct way to initialise this set?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take out the `=`.  Just invoke the constructor.

```
const set<string> obj::keywords (kw,kw + sizeof(kw)/sizeof(kw[0]));
```

Answer (score 24):

I'm wondering why you're using an array to initialize the `std::set`.

You could directly initialize the set as:

```
const set<string> obj::keywords {"GTR","LTR","LEQ","GEQ","NEQ","SQRT","sqrt"};
```

That is what you should be doing if you're using a compiler supporting C++11.

---

As for what is wrong with *your code*, as the other two answers says, remove `=`:

```
const string kw[] = {"GTR","LTR","LEQ","GEQ","NEQ","SQRT","sqrt"};
const set<string> obj::keywords(kw,kw + sizeof(kw)/sizeof(kw[0]));
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I very much agree. I kind of assumed it was C++03, but this is still valuable for others even if the OP is using C++03. Also, it might be worth noting that out of the main three, it's only MSVC that doesn't have the proper initializer list constructors yet.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the equals sign:

```
const set<string> obj::keywords(kw,kw + sizeof(kw)/sizeof(kw[0]));
```

What's happening is the dreaded comma operator. First, it evaluates `kw` and throws away the result. Next, it evaluates `kw + sizeof(kw)/sizeof(kw[0])` and tries to copy-initialize `keywords` with that.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder why no-one suggested `boost::assign` from `<boost/assign/list_of.hpp>`

```
static const set<string> keywords = boost::assign::list_of("GTR")("SQRT")("whatever you need");
```

This way is less typing, but has weird syntax, because every item is between parentheses and there is no comma.

---

If you are using C++11 it is better use the way [Nawaz suggested in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16351491/1237747). My answer just shown another possible method and (in my opinion) better option for old standard.